# Anyone know why pacman is not respecting the walls? When i press the keys to move pacman teleports between the walls

Tags: python, pygame, pacman

i'm trying to make a pacman game like pygame, now i just want him to walk through the maze without going beyond the walls of the maze. However I have faced some problems, when I press the keys to move the pacman, he ends up telephoning between the walls, although he does not exceed them it ends up bugging the coordinate system and starts to give a series of errors during the game commands . Does anyone know why this is happening and how to solve it?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), 0)
# Color used in the game
YELLOW = (255,255,0)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
BLUE = (13,56,143)
speed = 1
class Scenery:
    def __init__(self, size, character):
        self.character = character
        self.size = size 
        self.matrix = [
            [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
            [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
            [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2],
            [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2],
            [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2],
            [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2],
            [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2],
            [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
            [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
        ]
    def paint_line(self, surface, line_index, line):
        for column_index, column in enumerate(line):
            x_box = column_index * self.size
            y_box = line_index * self.size
            half_size = self.size // 2
            color = BLACK
            if column == 2:
                color = BLUE
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, (x_box, y_box, self.size, self.size), 0)
            if column == 1:
                pygame.draw.circle(surface, YELLOW, (x_box + half_size, y_box + half_size), self.size//10, 0)
    def paint_scenery(self, surface):
        for line_index, line in enumerate(self.matrix):
            self.paint_line(surface, line_index, line)
    def calculate_rules(self):
        column_character = self.character.intention_column
        line_character = self.character.intention_line    
        if 0 <= column_character < 28 and 0 <= line_character < 29: 
            if self.matrix[line_character][column_character] != 2:
                self.character.aprove_movement() 
class Pacman:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.column = 1
        self.line = 1
        self.x_center = 400
        self.y_center = 300
        self.size = size # 2x radius and size/number of the cells
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.radius = self.size // 2
        self.intention_column = self.column
        self.intention_line = self.line

    def calculate_rules(self):
        # calculate the movimentantion
        self.intention_column =  self.intention_column + self.speed_x
        self.intention_line = self.intention_line + self.speed_y
        self.x_center = int( self.column * self.size + self.radius ) 
        self.y_center = int( self.line * self.size + self.radius )

    def draw_pacman(self, surface):
        # Draw pacman's character
        pacman_body = pygame.draw.circle(surface, YELLOW, (self.x_center, self.y_center), self.radius, 0)
        
        
        # Coordinates
        x_eye_position = ( self.x_center + int( self.radius/4 ) )
        y_eye_position = ( self.y_center - int( (self.radius/2) ) )
        point_a = (self.x_center, self.y_center) # Center
        point_b = ((self.x_center + self.radius), self.y_center) # Right Center
        point_c = ((self.x_center + self.radius), (self.y_center - self.radius)) # Superior Right Center
        points = [point_a, point_b, point_c]
        # Pacman 
        pacman_eye = pygame.draw.circle(surface, BLACK, (x_eye_position, y_eye_position), int(self.radius/10), 0)
        pacman_mouth = pygame.draw.polygon(surface, BLACK, points, 0)
        # Make the draws
        pacman_body 
        pacman_eye
        pacman_mouth
    
    def calculate_events(self, events):
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT: # check if the user have clicked on the X box to quit
                exit()
            elif e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or e.key == pygame.K_d:
                    self.speed_x = speed
                elif e.key == pygame.K_LEFT or e.key == pygame.K_a:
                    self.speed_x = -speed
                elif e.key == pygame.K_UP or e.key == pygame.K_w:
                    self.speed_y = -speed
                elif e.key == pygame.K_DOWN or e.key == pygame.K_s:
                    self.speed_y = speed
            elif e.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if e.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or e.key == pygame.K_d:
                    self.speed_x = 0
                elif e.key == pygame.K_LEFT or e.key == pygame.K_a:
                    self.speed_x = 0
                elif e.key == pygame.K_UP or e.key == pygame.K_w:
                    self.speed_y = 0
                elif e.key == pygame.K_DOWN or e.key == pygame.K_s:
                    self.speed_y = 0

    def aprove_movement(self):
        self.column = self.intention_column
        self.line = self.intention_line
       
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = 600 // 30
    pacman = Pacman(size)
    scenary = Scenery(size, pacman)  
    

    while True:

        # Game Rules
        pacman.calculate_rules()
        scenary.calculate_rules()

        
        # Figures
        window.fill(BLACK)
        scenary.paint_scenery(window)
        pacman.draw_pacman(window)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.delay(100)

        
        events = pygame.event.get()
        pacman.calculate_events(events)
```

SO every time i hold the keys to move for a few seconds the pacman goes over the blue walls of the project, does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Looks like he just teleports to the other sides and than bug the role coordinate system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

1. The `intention_column`  and `intention_line` depends on the current `colume` and `line` instead of the previous `intention_column`  and `intention_line`. `intention_column`  and `intention_line` are incremented even if there is a wall. `colume` and `line` however are only incremented if the movement is possible:

```py
class Pacman:
    # [...]

    def calculate_rules(self):
        # calculate the movimentantion
        self.intention_column =  self.column + self.speed_x
        self.intention_line = self.line + self.speed_y
```

2. Only update `x_center` and `y_center` if `column` or `line` are changed:

```py
class Pacman:
    # [...]

    def aprove_movement(self):
        self.column = self.intention_column
        self.line = self.intention_line
        self.x_center = int( self.column * self.size + self.radius ) 
        self.y_center = int( self.line * self.size + self.radius )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I lost my wenesday afternon trying to find this issues.

Comment: @GustavoFigueiredo Thank you. You're welcome.